# How to build the whole web site from css design

Tags: html, css

This is a novice question.  I was given a web page design with CSS files and AI (Adobe Illustrator) files.  My task is to create the web contents properly.  What is the easiest way going about?  Can Dreamweaver come handy here?  Or do I have to code the html manually?  (I am sure there should be a better way).  The site is supposed to be up in a .NET environment.

Thank you for the help

Comment: If you have no web design experience, which it looks like you do not then you are going to struggle with this job. The short answer is No this is not possible you need html. "do I have to code the html manually? (I am sure there should be a better way)" There is no "better" way, unless you want to use a CMS like WordPress and use a default template, if your designing a custom template you need to code that template in html and css. I recommend you learn about what  web design is if you are going to do it ;)

Comment: "I am sure there should be a better way", is there anything better than coding the HTML manually? I don't think so.

Comment: What is a "CSS design"?

Comment: I think it is outright impossible to find a better way than to write the HTML manually. I haven't found any.
Take a look at www.w3schools.com

Comment: But then also take a look at http://www.w3fools.com/ ;)

Comment: Why were you provided with CSS files without any HTML? The rules in your CSS file reference your HTML elements, you can't build out your CSS file without an HTML document. Are you sure there wasn't an oversight and they simply forgot to provide you the HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS needs the HTML for structure and normally the two are written hand in hand. Spend the extra time and write the HTML and CSS manually while slicing up the supplied artwork. It's a rewarding process if you are learning or you challenge yourself to do a really good job of it. You can probably salvage a lot of css from the existing stylesheets (typography styles etc). In this way you can be more confident about the code you are using and ensure that it is legible. The HTML templates can then be integrated into a CMS, .NET framework based system or whatever the next step is.

If you are not up for the task, outsource the job to someone who is passionate about HTML and CSS to supply the complete HTML and CSS templates. There are plenty of us out there ;)